# how to bind tab layout with bottom navigation and view pager?

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager, android-tablayout, bottomnavigationview

[Navigation sheet Image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tysfA.png)

In above picture there is a `bottom navigation sheet` and a `view pager` for it's fragments and inside fragment i think is tab layout so my question is how  can do that in my application.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

you can use [AHBottomNavigation](https://github.com/aurelhubert/ahbottomnavigation) library.
please read it's document.